# Can I use excluding at the end of expression of interval?

Tags: word-usage

I want to express the fact that first part one of an XML file extents from the beginning to the Parameters section, but it does not include Parameters section.

Can I express it like this:

> The first section extends from the beginning of the file to the
>   Parameters section excluding?

If not, is there some other way of using word **excluding** in such expression?

Answer (score 1):

The first section extends from the beginning of the file up to but excluding the Parameters section.